almost surely converges and partial sum
Consider a series random variable $\{X_n\}$. Suppose
(1) $X_n$ converges to zero almost surely;
(2) $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.
I want to know whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X_n]$ is finite or not. I know the sum can be infinite with only conditions (1) or (2), but what happens if both conditions need to be held?

What if $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of real numbers and $\forall \omega \in \Omega, X_n(\omega) = x_n$ ?

Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, and define
$$
X_n:=\cases{1,&if $U\in(0,1/n]$,\cr  0,&if $U\in(1/n,1)$.\cr
}
$$
Then $X_n\to 0$ a.s., $\Bbb E[X_n]=1/n\to 0$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb E[X_n]$ diverges.

Got it. Thanks a lot!
